# Add an input to choose a folder to scan with pathLib

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still new to coding so this might be dumb but i'm trying to write a Python code so it can scan all files in a specific folder on my pc to determine the most frequently used word (useless but trying to improve sooo).

I wrote in the code what folder i want to scan, and it works great.

So i tried to put an input here, so the user can choose what file he wants to scan, but i didn't succeed and i don't really know why.

I don't know if this is understandable, but in the second line, instead of the ""pathlib.Path(str...)))"", it was ""pathlib.Path(r"C:\ ... ")""

Any advices?

```
import pathlib

folder = pathlib.Path(str(input("What folder do you want to scan? : ")))

stats = {}

for path in folder.iterdir():
    file = open(str(path))
    text = file.read().lower()
```

Comment: You don't need `str()` around `input()`. It always returns a string.

Answer (score 1):

`iterdir()` will return files and directories, but you can only open files. So you need to check if `path` is a file or directory before trying to open and read it.

```
for path in folder.iterdir():
    if path.is_file():
        with open(path) as file:
            text = file.read().lower()
            print(text)
```

There's no need to call `str(path)`, as `open()` can take `Path` objects.